# Align Symbols in Nodes Circuitikz

Tags: symbols, nodes, circuitikz

I have a little Problem, that I can't solve with Circuitikz. I want to change the layout of all my nodes. I want them to look like this:

[image: circuitikz label]

After some while I managed to change the dot and the proportions of the Gate with ctikzset. My Code is the following:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{tripoles/european not symbol=ieee circle,
tripoles/european nand port/height=1.1}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz} 
                \draw node[nand port,align=left](){};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

This Code gives me the following gate:

[image: my code nand]

Now my two questions:

1. How can I move the "&"-symbol to the of the gate?
2. Is there an option to change the height for all ports together? (at the moment I type:

   ```latex
   tripoles/european and port/height=1.1,
   tripoles/european nand port/height=1.1,
   tripoles/european or port/height=1.1,
   tripoles/european nor port/height=1.1,
   tripoles/european not port/height=1.1,
   ```

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can patch the definition of the `european` ports with a different text definition, and then re-issue the declarations. You need to re-declare all the heights, yes --- this is a historical thing for circuitikz, and I'd like to change it (using a default per-class and possible override), but it's a quite long thing and error-prone...

To change everything you can do this:

```latex
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\pgfcircdeclareeurologicport}%
{%
\pgftext{#2}
}{%
\pgftext[y=\pgf@circ@res@up-4pt, top]{#2}
}{\typeout{Patching OK}}{\typeout{Patching failed}}
% fast change-all macro
\ctikzset{european ports height/.style={%
    % height change
    tripoles/european and port/height=#1,
    tripoles/european or port/height=#1,
    tripoles/european xor port/height=#1,
    tripoles/european not port/height=#1,
    tripoles/european buffer port/height=#1,
    tripoles/european nand port/height=#1,
    tripoles/european xor port/height=#1,
    tripoles/european xnor port/height=#1
}}
% redefine the ports
\pgfcircdeclareeurologicport{and}{\&}{\pgf@circ@res@count}{}
\pgfcircdeclareeurologicport{or}{$\ge 1$}{\pgf@circ@res@count}{}
\pgfcircdeclareeurologicport{xor}{$=1$}{\pgf@circ@res@count}{}
\pgfcircdeclareeurologicport{not}{$1$}{1}{not}
\pgfcircdeclareeurologicport{buffer}{$1$}{1}{}
\pgfcircdeclareeurologicport{nand}{\&}{\pgf@circ@res@count}{not}
\pgfcircdeclareeurologicport{nor}{$\ge 1$}{\pgf@circ@res@count}{not}
\pgfcircdeclareeurologicport{xnor}{$=1$}{\pgf@circ@res@count}{not}
\makeatother
\ctikzset{%
    logic ports origin=center,
    european ports height=1.1,
    tripoles/european not symbol=ieee circle,
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}
        \draw (0,0) node[nand port,align=left](){};
        \draw (2,0) node[nand port,align=left, rotate=90](){};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice however that European sorts are not thought to be used vertically, because the symbol *does not* rotate. That can be adjusted too, if needed; if you change the patch command to:

```latex
\patchcmd{\pgfcircdeclareeurologicport}%
{%
\pgftext{#2}
}{%
\pgfgettransformentries\a\b\temp\temp\temp\temp
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rot}{-atan2(\b,\a)}
\pgftext[y=\pgf@circ@res@up-8pt, rotate=\rot]{#2}
}{\typeout{Patching OK}}{\typeout{Patching failed}}
```

and the body to:

```
 \draw (0,0) node[nand port,align=left](){};
 \draw (2,0) node[nand port,align=left, rotate=90](){};
 \draw (4,0) node[nand port,align=left, rotate=-90](){};
 \draw (6,0) node[nand port,align=left, rotate=45](){};
```

you'll have:

[image]

This is not optimal because you have to hand-adjust the `8pt` over there depending on the font size, but it works...

Answer (score 6):

This is a possible answer. (Disclaimer: this is guess work.) If you increase `2.5em` the ampersand will get lifted even more.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{tripoles/european not symbol=ieee circle,
tripoles/european nand port/height=1.1}
\makeatletter
\ctikzset{tripoles/port height/.code={\ctikzset{tripoles/european and port/height=#1,
tripoles/european nand port/height=#1,
tripoles/european or port/height=#1,
tripoles/european nor port/height=#1,
tripoles/european not port/height=#1}}}
\pgfcircdeclareeurologicport{nand}{\raisebox{2.5em}{\&}}{\pgf@circ@res@count}{not}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[circuitikz/tripoles/port height=0.9] 
                \draw node[nand port,align=left](){};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option with which you do not have to guess an argument of a `\raisebox` is to employ the `append after command` key and let Ti*k*Z place the ampersand.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{tripoles/european not symbol=ieee circle,
tripoles/european nand port/height=1.1}
\makeatletter
\ctikzset{tripoles/port height/.code={\ctikzset{tripoles/european and port/height=#1,
tripoles/european nand port/height=#1,
tripoles/european or port/height=#1,
tripoles/european nor port/height=#1,
tripoles/european not port/height=#1}}}
\tikzset{nand port/.append style={append after command={
(\tikzlastnode.north) node[below]{\&}}}}
\pgfcircdeclareeurologicport{nand}{}{\pgf@circ@res@count}{not}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[circuitikz/tripoles/port height=0.9] 
                \draw node[nand port,align=left](){};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The Part, that all changes to the same height does not really work, but that was not the important part. It works for every "normal" port, but when I rotate it, the symbol is in the right down corner. Do you have an Idea how to fix that?

Comment: @pfennig Hmmh. Did you add `transform shape` when you rotated the shape?

Comment: I did, but it didnt work. @Rmano gave the Solution, but thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[european]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{tripoles/european not symbol=ieee circle,
tripoles/european nand port/height=1.1}

\makeatletter
\pgfcircdeclareeurologicport{nand}{}{\pgf@circ@res@count}{not}% remove & symbol at \pgfpointorigin
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz} 
      \draw node[nand port,align=left](nand1){}
        (nand1.north) node[below] {\&};% add & symbol
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see, what you are doing, but that would mean, that I needed to change all ports in my Document... It's a solid answer though